# Étymologie de « auparavant »

Tags: étymologie

> [[D'après Wiktionary:]](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/auparavant) → voir [au](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/au), [**part**](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/part) et [avant](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avant).
>
> [[D'après CNRTL:]](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/auparavant) ... Composé de au (a-<sup>1*</sup>), **par*** et avant*; cf. ca 1243 *par avant* adv. ...

1. Le morphème au milieu, est-il « part » ou « par » ? Que signifie-t-il ici ?
2. Ces 3 morphèmes : comment se sont-ils combinés à générer le sens actuel ?
   Quelles notions sémantiques les sous-tendent ?

Answer (score 4):

**Avant** provient d'un latin « *abante* » <sup>1</sup> qui provient d'un autre latin « *ab ante* ». Le sens d' « [avant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/avant?idf=dmfXdXrmXacabe;str=0) » (10e s.) repose au départ sur la composante *temporelle* comme *adverbe*. Le sens spatial suit. L'emploi en préposition arrive deux siècles plus tard avec « *en avant* qqc. ». Du côté spatial, on avait *davant* (10e s.), éventuellement [*devant*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/devant?idf=dmfXgXrmXdgea;str=0) (11e s.) qui s'y opposaient pour le contrôle du sens. [*Par avant/paravant*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/paravant?idf=dmfXgXrmXpbca;str=0) comme locution adverbiale remonte au 13e siècle (disparaît au 17e sauf dans le *burlesque* (*Le Bon Usage*, Grevisse, Goosse, *ed. Duculot*; 965 e 3); on y ajoute *au-* pour obtenir [auparavant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/auparavant) au 14e siècle.<sup>2</sup>

---

*Observations diverses*

- *Par avant* avec le sens d'*auparavant* : « *le vicaire-général [...] ne pouvait deviner [...] si la mère était par avant jalouse.* » (Balzac, *A. Savarus*, Pl., p. 764)
- *avant* et *devant* (*LBU*, 1054) :

  - [*Devant*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/devant) marque le lieu; pour indiquer le temps c'est maintenant un archaïsme ou un régionalisme (« *nous nous sommes levés devant l'aube* »), mais ça reste dans « *rester Gros-Jean comme devant* » avec le sens exact d'*auparavant* (*LBU*, 1004 b 2).
  - *Avant* marque normalement le temps et nécessite une forme d'adéquation entre le temps et le déplacement pour pouvoir marquer le lieu; on donne « *à droite avant* (un lieu) », c'est-à-dire une succession d'étapes. Les emplois adjectivaux avec *avant* permettent parfois le lieu comme dans les « portières avant [...] » (voir aussi avec intérêt la discussion avec [*d'avant*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avant))
- En ce qui a trait au choix de l'*Académie* en 2001 de considérer « *mettre la charrue avant les bœufs* » avec la variante « *devant* », pour exprimer le « lieu » (*LBU*, 1054 R3) : il s'agirait plutôt de l'idée de temps aujourd'hui. On explique une transition d'une logique de « *mettre devant ce qui doit être derrière* » vers celle de « *faire avant ce qui devrait être fait après* », et finalement « *commencer par où on devrait finir* ».
- *Auparavant* a déjà été utilisé comme préposition (*LBU*, 1039 H3) avec l'exemple « *arrivé auparavant lui* »; Monsieur Vaugelas<sup>3</sup> n'en était point, autant que pour « du depuis » (*LBU*, 1040 H1).
- On parle aussi de « avant » comme préposition avec un régime implicite (*LBU*, 1040 1 a), et on donne : « *Avant, nous étions souillés par l'envahisseur. Maintenant* [...] ».
- Il y avait divers substantifs en composition avec *avant* en [préfixe](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/avant).
- L'homonyme [*paravent*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/paravent), substantif, fait son entrée en 1599 avec la graphie *paravant*, qu'il conserve pendant une vingtaine d'années.

---

Sans pouvoir dire pourquoi exactement on a au+paravant, sinon que ça ressemble beaucoup à la forme latine (*abante*), on constate l'évolution des formes et des usages et la compétition des prépositions et adverbes, la répartition des sens entre les termes, et un certain équilibre. En fait on peut penser à bien des choses qui peuvent s'affronter afin de rendre le même sens au fil du temps. Plusieurs constructions plus anciennes sont rendues par « auparavant » aujourd'hui. Ça me rappelle quand on avait « [hui](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/hui2?idf=dmfXgXrmXhcgh;str=0) » (lat. *hodie*) pouvant signifier *aujourd'hui*, qui lui se décline littéralement comme *au jour de ce jour*, une curiosité : il n'y a pas d'ajout au sens, alors que c'est plutôt la graphie qui se charge, mais dans la « direction » du mot latin d'origine pour ainsi dire. En anglais on a [*by-fore, beforehand*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=before&searchmode=none), *herebefore*, qu'il serait sans doute intéressant de comparer à cet effet. J'espère qu'on pourra continuer la recherche pour en apprendre plus (avant) sur le sujet.

---

<sub>**1.** À « [*abante*](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=abante) », le *Gaffiot* donne « adv. devant : Firm, [Math. 2,22](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/thayer/l/roman/texts/Firmicus_Maternus/Mathesis/2*.html) [*Dextrum trigonum est, quod ab eo signo, a quo incipimus, retro est, sinistrum vero, quod abante*;] - prép. acc. : [Vulg.](https://archive.org/stream/bibliasacravulga00pezz#page/602/mode/2up/search/%22ab+ante%22)[je vois seulement en deux mots : *Visa itaque turba de retro, et ab ante, adorantes dicite in cordibus vestris: Te oportet adorari Domine.*] ». [Lewis](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DA%3Aentry%20group%3D1%3Aentry%3Dabante) : « I. Prep. with abl., *from before*: “abante oculis parcntis rapuerunt nymphae,” *away before the eyes of the father*, *Inscr. Grut*. 717, 11.; II. Adv., *before*: “ne (quis) abante aliam (arcam) ponat,” *Inscr. Orell*. 4396. ». Voir aussi [*DuCange*](http://ducange.enc.sorbonne.fr/ABANTE). En passant, on peut en profiter pour lire *a, ab* au Gaffiot; on note au sens IV « [à partir de](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?p=2) ». C'est que si on pense à *ab initio* par exemple, on peut penser à « dès le/depuis le/du début » ou à « à partir du début »; on a ça avec l'idée d'*antériorité* ici.</sub>

<sub>**2.** Le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sous dir. d'A. Rey, *ed. Le Robert*, expose les éléments de cette séquence à « avant ».</sub>

<sub>**3.** M. [*Vaugelas*](https://archive.org/stream/remarquessurlala02vaug#page/18/mode/2up/search/%22langage+barbare%22) aide à comprendre, dans un ordre d'idées un peu différent, l'air du temps - *trois siècles après « auparavant »* - au 17e :</sub>

> <sub>Il faut dire *avant que de mourir*, et *devant que de mourir*, et non
>   pas *avant que mourir* ny *devant que mourir*, et beaucoup moins
>   encore *avant mourir*, comme disent quelques-uns en langage barbare.</sub>
>
> <sub>[ *Remarques sur la langue Françoise de Monsieur de Vaugelas: utiles à
>   ceux qui veulent bien parler et bien escrire. t.2* - [M. Claude Favre
>   de Vaugelas](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Favre_de_Vaugelas) ]</sub>

<sub>C'est que « *avant* » en préposition suivi immédiatement de l'infinitif était en usage jusqu'au 16e siècle. La réaction illustre que les sensibilités changent avec les époques, indépendamment du sens.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

1. : selon le Robert, c'est **par** qui est correcte
2. : Pour le comprendre intuitivement,

   - il faut prendre *avant* comme pivot du sens.
   - on peut utiliser une béquille en pensant "*on part d'avant*", contracté en *aupar-*  ce qui expliquerait le ***t*** ajouté dans le Wiktionnaire, mais pas le *au* ajouté.
   - ou prendre *par*, dont une des acceptions est *au moyen de* : au moyen (de ce qui est) avant *[au par avant]*...  l'explication arrive.